# How enable http and https with wcf service?

Tags: wcf, http, iis, https, web-config

I need publish a wcf service, and this should be accessed with Http and Https protocols. 
I tried to configure this in my server, but the problem with is that only one of this protocols can work.

Is it possible?

This is my Web.config code:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfiguration">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviorConfiguration">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviorConfiguration" >
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfiguration" name="TestSvc" contract="ServiceTest.ITest" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but in a way you might not expect. You host your service on HTTPS. Then create another site on the same pool. This site is HTTP and it contains only web.config file looking like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://your_https_url" exactDestination="true" childOnly="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Now every time someone tries to use the HTTP site will be automatically redirected to HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Try using multiple endpoints for same service one with basicHttpBindind and one with wsHttpBinding

```
<service name="NorthwindServices.Services.CustomerService" 
                behaviorConfiguration ="ServiceBehavior">
<host>
  <baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:7741/NorthwindServices/Services
                        /CustomerService" /> 
    <add baseAddress="https://localhost:4512/Services/CustomerService" />
   </baseAddresses>
</host>

<endpoint address ="" binding="wsHttpBinding"
    contract="NorthwindServices.ServiceContracts.ICustomerService"
    bindingNamespace = "http://dotnetmentors.com/services/customer" />
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
            contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

<endpoint address ="" binding ="basicHttpBinding" 
    contract ="NorthwindServices.ServiceContracts.ICustomerService"
    bindingNamespace = "http://dotnetmentors.com/services/customer"  />
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
            contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
</service>
```